# What is the minimum information required to define an equation for ellipse?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

What is the minimum information ie. amount of points in 2-dimensional plane in order to define the equation for an ellipse?

I know that unique ellipse cannot be defined when only one of the foci is known in addition to two points in the ellipses path.

I also know, that we can define unique ellipse when both foci are known and the distance from both of them onto point in ellipse (this is as far as I know the least information required).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am interpreting the question as asking for a minimum number of points that determine a unique ellipse passing through them.

Four points is not enough. The two ellipses
$$
x^2+2y^2=3\qquad\text{and}\qquad 2x^2+y^2=3
$$
both pass through the points $(x,y)=(\pm1,\pm1)$ (all four sign combinations).

Five points $P_j=(x_j,y_j), j=1,2,3,4,5,$ (in general) does suffice. But we get more than we bargained for. Namely five points determine a conic. The general quadratic equation
$$
a_1x^2+a_2xy+a_3y^2+a_4x+a_5y+a_6=0\qquad(*)
$$
has six unknown coefficients. By plugging in the coordinates of the points $P_j$ we get a homogeneous system of five equations in the six unknowns. Linear algebra then tells us that the system has a non-trivial solution. Usually the solution is determined up to a scalar multiple, but scaling all the coefficients in $(*)$ won't change the curve, so we can ignore that.

Two caveats:

- The resulting conic may be a hyperbola, parabola, or even two intersecting lines - not necessarily an ellipse. All depending.
- The system that we get may have a 2-dimensional solution space (in which case the curve would not be determined uniquely). But this happens only, when some subset of four points are collinear, so we will not encounter this problem when looking at ellipses. Though well known, this fact is not immediately obvious, and needs an argument. In [Joe Harris' book](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/algebra/book/978-0-387-97716-4) this is an exercise, but does follow from a more general theorem (Theorem 1.18) stating that through any $d+3$ points in general position in $\Bbb{P}^d$ there passes a unique rational normal curve.

Comment: _"Four points is not enough."_ Your example only says that you can define four points so that there are at least two different ellipses through these points. But the question should be whether for each ellipse you can define four points so that there are no other ellipse going through these points, which is different.

Comment: @JiK: That example is kinda generic. Take any non-circular ellipse. Rotate it 90 degrees (actually nearly any angle will do) about the center. The two ellipses intersect at four points. But your point stands. I will edit the answer. When I find the time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following equation defines an ellipse:

$\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2} + \sqrt{(x-x_2)^2 + (y-y_2)^2} = 2a$

The foci are the two points: $(x_1,y_1) , (x_2,y_2)$

Since there are 5 unknown, there is a need for 5 points.

Comment: Time to do some rethinking?! Three (non-collinear) points do determine a unique circle through them. But, consequently, cannot determine a unique ellipse. Take a non-circular ellipse, and pick 3 points on it. There will also be a circle through those points.

Comment: You are right! This means that it is still 3 points, but at the foci is required, as in the circle case if you have the center one point on the circle is enough. I wonder if one foci and two points will suffice.

Comment: @Moti I know, that two points + one focus isn't enought.

Comment: You are right again! I edited my answer. You need five points!